# Realm duplicate Objects

Tags: ios, swift, realm

In my CoreData version I could write

```
let doubledContacts = contacts + contacts
```

where contacts was of type [NSManagedObject]. In Realm this forces a crash: "Can't mutate a persisted array outside of a write transaction."

I don't want to persist doubledContacts so I don't need a write transaction. All I want is a new collection where every contact is contained twice.

How do I solve this in Realm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to pull all contacts in an array:

```
 let contactsArray = contacts.map { $0 }
 let doubledContacts = contactsArray + contactsArray
```

But note: that will set lazy semantics of `List` (or `Results`) out of effect and cause that you pull all object instances into mapped memory.